# How to pass a single value argument to a JSON file from a script without overriding the existing values?

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON file named `pool.json`:

```json
{
   "AllocateActions": {},
   "Available": true,
   "Description": "Pool for nodes in cluster - {{CLUSTER_NAME}}",
   "Endpoint": "",
   "EnterActions": {
     "AddProfiles": [
       "{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}",
       "image-deploy-profile",
       "rc-controlplane-profile",
       "rc-etcd-profile"
     ],
     "Workflow": "rc-image-deploy"
   },
   "Errors": [],
   "ExitActions": {
     "RemoveProfiles": [
       "{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}",
       "image-deploy-profile"
     ],
     "Workflow": "discover-base"
   },
   "Meta": {
     "color": "black",
     "feature-flags": "sane-exit-codes",
     "icon": "object ungroup outline",
     "title": "User added"
   },
   "ReadOnly": true,
   "ReleaseActions": {},
   "Validated": true
 }
```

From my bash script, I am using `jq` to pass the values to these JSON placeholders:

```bash
NODE_JSON=$(jq --arg RC_JOIN_PROFILE "$RC_JOIN_PROFILE" --arg CLUSTER_NAME "$CLUSTER_NAME" '.Description = "'$CLUSTER_NAME'"| .ExitActions.RemoveProfiles = [ "'$RC_JOIN_PROFILE'" ] | .EnterActions.AddProfiles = [ "'$RC_JOIN_PROFILE'" ]' pool.json)
```

If I am passing `RC_JOIN_PROFILE="test-profile"` and `CLUSTER_NAME="test-cluster"`, then I was expecting the final JSON as follows:

```json
{
   "AllocateActions": {},
   "Available": true,
   "Description": "Pool for nodes in cluster - test-cluster",
   "Endpoint": "",
   "EnterActions": {
     "AddProfiles": [
       "test-profile",
       "image-deploy-profile",
       "rc-controlplane-profile",
       "rc-etcd-profile"
     ],
     "Workflow": "rc-image-deploy"
   },
   "Errors": [],
   "ExitActions": {
     "RemoveProfiles": [
       "test-profile",
       "image-deploy-profile"
     ],
     "Workflow": "discover-base"
   },
   "Meta": {
     "color": "black",
     "feature-flags": "sane-exit-codes",
     "icon": "object ungroup outline",
     "title": "User added"
   },
   "ReadOnly": true,
   "ReleaseActions": {},
   "Validated": true
 }
```

However, I am getting JSON below instead:

```json
{
   "AllocateActions": {},
   "Available": true,
   "Description": "test-cluster",
   "Endpoint": "",
   "EnterActions": {
     "AddProfiles": [
       "test-profile",
     ],
     "Workflow": "rc-image-deploy"
   },
   "Errors": [],
   "ExitActions": {
     "RemoveProfiles": [
       "test-profile",
     ],
     "Workflow": "discover-base"
   },
   "Meta": {
     "color": "black",
     "feature-flags": "sane-exit-codes",
     "icon": "object ungroup outline",
     "title": "User added"
   },
   "ReadOnly": true,
   "ReleaseActions": {},
   "Validated": true
 }
```

The existing values of `.ExitActions.AddPofiles`, `.ExitActions.RemoveProfiles` and `.Description` have been overwritten by the passed values. I want the existing values with passed values. I tried many scenarios, and nothing worked. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main issues with your code:

1. You define `jq` variables that you never use.
2. You *set* the arrays to the values rather than update them.
3. You do not attempt to match the template placeholders.

Instead, pass the values to internal `jq` variables, use `sub()` to substitute the template placeholders with the appropriate values, use the `|=` operator to simplify updating the necessary data (`a |= expression` is the same as `a = (a | expression)`).

```bash
jq --arg clustername "$CLUSTER_NAME" --arg profilename "$RC_JOIN_PROFILE" '
    .Description                |=     sub("{{CLUSTER_NAME}}";    $clustername) |
    .EnterActions.AddProfiles   |= map(sub("{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}"; $profilename)) |
    .ExitActions.RemoveProfiles |= map(sub("{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}"; $profilename))' pool.json
```

Here, the three bits in the input JSON that have template placeholders are updated with `sub()` to substitute the placeholders with the appropriate value.  The two arrays are processed by mapping the `sub()` call to each of their elements, so that we don't have to rely on where in the array the placeholders are located.

If you want to only affect the first element of the arrays, then use e.g.

```
.ExitActions.RemoveProfiles[0] |= sub("{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}"; $profilename)
```

or, if you just want to *assign* the value to the first element of the array,

```
.ExitActions.RemoveProfiles[0] = $profilename
```

(and similarly for the first array, without using `map()`).

Example run on the given data:

```bash
$ CLUSTER_NAME='Test Cluster Name "Charlie"'
$ RC_JOIN_PROFILE='Test RC Join Profile "Matilda"'
$ jq --arg clustername "$CLUSTER_NAME" --arg profilename "$RC_JOIN_PROFILE" '.Description |= sub("{{CLUSTER_NAME}}"; $clustername) | .EnterActions.AddProfiles |= map(sub("{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}"; $profilename)) | .ExitActions.RemoveProfiles |= map(sub("{{RC_JOIN_PROFILE}}"; $profilename))' pool.json
{
  "AllocateActions": {},
  "Available": true,
  "Description": "Pool for nodes in cluster - Test Cluster Name \"Charlie\"",
  "Endpoint": "",
  "EnterActions": {
    "AddProfiles": [
      "Test RC Join Profile \"Matilda\"",
      "image-deploy-profile",
      "rc-controlplane-profile",
      "rc-etcd-profile"
    ],
    "Workflow": "rc-image-deploy"
  },
  "Errors": [],
  "ExitActions": {
    "RemoveProfiles": [
      "Test RC Join Profile \"Matilda\"",
      "image-deploy-profile"
    ],
    "Workflow": "discover-base"
  },
  "Meta": {
    "color": "black",
    "feature-flags": "sane-exit-codes",
    "icon": "object ungroup outline",
    "title": "User added"
  },
  "ReadOnly": true,
  "ReleaseActions": {},
  "Validated": true
}
```

Note that we, by using the `jq` variables `clustername` and `profilename` that we define on the command line with `--arg`, can rely on `jq` to handle the quoting of the strings correctly.